# How can I access the content of the tables on a schema in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I have a python connection to a Red Shift database that it's organized with schemas. I am able to access all the schemas names and table names but I'm unable to load any specific table within any schema. It seems like I can connect to the database but I can't browse further. Any ideas?

When I write a query without specifying the schema name it gives me the following error:

*UndefinedTable: relation "table_name" does not exist*

I'm using psycopg2 for building the connection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify [search_path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html) to a schemas if you want to not use schema name in a query

let say I have `schema1` with table `table1` in there, and my default search path is `$user, public`. If I want to query `table1` I have to use it in query

```sql
select * from schema1.table1;
```

but if I set `schema1` in my search_path

```sql
set search_path to schema1;
```

then I can query in this way

```sql
select * from table1;
```

Comment: Thanks @pavel. That’s what I was asking for